# Creating a MakeFile in C++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile

I have never made a makefile before and I have to turn one in for a project. I was sick and like a typical college student, a procrastinator. I understand the concepts and reasoning behind it i'm just curious like where to type it in command line and stuff.
Here are some details that were included

1) must be called Makefile

2)Must put the following at the type of my makefile specifying it run on g++ 4.7

PATH:= /usr/um/gcc-4.7.0/bin:$(PATH)

LD_LIBRARY_PATH:= /usr/um/gcc-4.7.0/lib64

LD_RUN_PATH:= /usr/um/gcc-4.7.0/lib64

Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/

Comment: Are you just asking us to write a makefile for you?  StackOverflow is not a free homework solution provider.  Look online.  Find a tutorial, an example, whatever.  There are hundreds of questions with examples in the answers on SO alone.  Try to figure it out.  If something doesn't work, ask a _specific question_ about the thing that doesn't work showing what you tried, what error you got, and maybe a guess as to what's wrong (but don't just include the guess without the rest).  Then we can help.

Answer (score 1):

Josh, did you play around with the link at mrbook.org/tutorials/make ?

First were you able to compile a program using your g++ 4.7 with an entry in the command line (without the makefile thing?)    Get that to work first.

After that read that link I sent you again, so you understand what is going on.  All the stuff you need is there.

And yeah, because its homework, we're not going to do it for you here.

On the procrastination thing I'm with ya... a minute early is a minute wasted.